# Google Plus list all activities

Tags: google-plus

I just tried using the Google Plus Api, and wanted to retrieve all the activities displayed on my front page. However, using the activities.list from the API gave me 0 results, since I never posted on Google Plus. Is there any way to obtain all the activities present there, like I would get all the posts on Facebook Wall? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the API allows you to get only your own posts.

Comment: That's what I thought, just needed a second opinion. I've seen people say that you could retrieve the post like in Facebook wall, but I guess they were wrong. Let's wait for a more open API! cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can get anyone's public activity! The only way to achieve the results, seen on your wall is a bit stupid, but is the only:)
1) get your friends via the "people/me/people/visible" edge and store user ID's;
2) cycle for each user for their public activities via "people/{user_id}/activities/public";

Good luck. :)